# Eloquent laravel --> Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, slim, eloquent

i have the next structure:

model call **content**

```
public function credits(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\models\Credit');
}
```

model call **Credit**

```
 public function content()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\models\Content');
}
```

---

What i am triying to do is extract all the credits of one content, but selecting only the columns that i want, with the below code:

```
$credits2=$this->content::with(array('credits'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','department','job');
 }))->where('id',$id_content)->get();
```

---

The problem that i have is that when i execute all the code the result is:

```
[]
```

but if i do a normal query in mysql i can figure out that for the movie exists credits.

I have extracted this code, from other forums, and stackoverflow post.

Comment: Looks like there is no `content` with `id = $id_content` in DB.

Comment: there is because i do a print of $id_content i search manually in the database and it return me the film

Comment: Put this code before your query `dd($this->content::find($id_content));`. What is the output?

Comment: is that a many to many relationship? your model relations are wrong i think

Comment: i have solved this, i am retarded. The $id_content was not a integer, was a object of a previous query. So if i change my querie to `$id_content->id` i have the problem solved. Sorry

Comment: @Ratchet in this case you do not need to execute this query, just use `load()` instead of `with()`. Like `$id_content->load(......);` This will save you one query to DB.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin i will investigate about the load, because i dont understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another easy way to specify columns without using closure:

```
 $credits2 = $this->content::with('credits:credits.id,department,job')
                  ->find($id_content->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that $id_content was a result from a previous query, so if i put $id_content didn't work, for that i have to access to the column.

And the solution is:

```
$credits2=$this->content::with(array('credits'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','department','job');
 }))->where('id',$id_content)->get();
```